# How do I create packages dynamically in perl?

Tags: perl, dynamic, package, compile-time

I've got a situation which would be helped if I could create packages dynamically.  The following code won't run, but illustrates the spirit of what I want to do.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $basename    = "Xma";
my $len     = 7;
my $newClass    = sprintf("%s%d", $basename, $len);

printf("New class is %s\n", $newClass);

package $newClass {
    # Early modules.
    our @enum; BEGIN { @enum = qw( I_VAL I_SLOPE ); }

    use parent qw(Exporter);
    use enum::fields @enum;
    our @EXPORT = (@enum);

    our $classLen = $len;
    our $classBasename = $basename;

    sub new {
    my $invocant = shift;
    my $self = bless ([], ref $invocant || $invocant);
    return($self);
    }
}

1;
```

I've included the "extra" stuff in my new class to illustrate that the new class is a complex one and it's going to be in an inheritance chain.

I know I can do simple packages with something like:

```
*{ "${class}::new" } = sub { return bless { }, $class };
```

But my new classes/packages are going to be pretty big, so I was hoping for something a little easier to maintain.

The curious among you might be asking, "Why?"  Curiosity is a big one.  I need to process process as much stuff as I can at load/compile time, and am trying to avoid several million runtime lookups.  I need to change `$basename` and `$len` frequently, but only at compile time.  And the big one: curiosity.

Comment: `eval($code)` You could use a template to generate `$code`.

Comment: Or `require($package_file)` (or `require Package::Name;`), if you build the package at runtime (and dump it to the file `$package_file`)

Comment: If you want a nice and complete but heavy API: [Moose::Meta::Class->create](http://p3rl.org/Moose::Meta::Class)

Comment: eval will execute your code so it will certainly do what you want ... but remember if your code is wrong you're in for a significant debug journey.  If you have a working template and only change a few parameters and include known working methods then you're minimising the possible headaches that come with a dynamic code approach.  This approach can also be used for code encryption - you read in an encrypted file, decrypt it and eval it.  (Which is only useful if you can protect the decryption process).

Comment: So, I was hoping for some sort of magic, and you all have provided it.  1) generate the dynamic code, 2) decide whether or not it persists on disk, 3) execute it, and all of this to avoid the clean, but slow (in this case) Moose.  First one to write it up gets the points. :)

Answer (score 4):

I hate to be the one to say it but variable code (?!) is quite the **anti-pattern** and a big red flag for most use cases I can think of, except for the obvious code generating tools or transpilers.

It is much preferable to just create a single class or class hierarchy then deal with whatever differences from within that class using non-meta programming.

In fact, that's the idea of OOP in general. You create objects which are instances or copies from a "template" which is your class:

```
  package MyClass {
       sub new {
           my ( $class, %args ) = @_;
           bless { name => sprintf('%s%d', $args{basename}, $args{len}) }, $class;
       }
  }

  my $obj = MyClass->new( basename => 'Xma', len => 7 );
  printf "New class is %s\n", $obj->{ name };
```

If you really really need to create packages/classes dynamically, the most sane approach I can think of is to create classes dynamically that inherit from one or more base classes.

```
package MyClass {  
    sub new {
        my ( $class, %args ) = @_;
        bless \%args, $class;
    }

    sub foo {
        my $self = shift;
        return "instance of $self";
    }
}

sub build_class {
    my ( %args ) = @_;

    my $classname = sprintf( '%s::%s%d', $args{ parent }, $args{ basename }, $args{ len } );
    @{ "${classname}::ISA" } = ( $args{ parent } );

    return $classname;
}

my $classname = build_class( parent => 'MyClass', basename => 'Xma', len => 7 );
my $obj = $classname->new();

printf "New class is %s\n", ref $obj;  # is MyClass::Xma7
printf "Object is an %s\n", $obj->foo; # a MyClass::Xma7=HASH(...) object instance
```

For more meta-programming power for your OOP, look into `Moose::Meta::Class` or `Class::MOP`:

```
use Class::MOP;

my $basename = 'Xma';
my $len = 7;
my $classname = "MyClass::${basename}${len}";

Class::MOP::Class->create(
    $classname,
    attributes => [
        Class::MOP::Attribute->new( 'foo', is => 'rw', isa => 'Str' )
    ],
    methods => {}
);

$classname->new( foo => 'bar' );
```

On the other hand, if you really need to have variable code within your packages and/or you don't need/want to load all packages in memory at runtime everytime your program runs, I would say you can use **a set of file templates and some template language** of your choice to output your new packages to files (ie. "MyClass/Xma7.pm", "MyClass/Xma8.pm") then load them using `use MyClasses::Xma7;` just like with any other package. The advantage here is that your code will much easier to debug and test given the error proneness of meta-programming.

Comment: Generally, this is true.  This particularly odd case is millions of mathematical transformations, and comparing them to each other.  If run-time speed considerations weren't a factor, I'd use a crisp, clean `compute("Xma",[0..1000])` sort of affair.  The profiling suggests that the lookups of the hashes become a problem on the hardware I'm using.  But mostly, it was curiosity.  If/when speed becomes a super big deal, I'll probably switch to `C`.  If that isn't fast enough, I'll give up, because it hasn't been long enough since I've written in `ForTran` that I've forgotten the scars it leaves.

Comment: Someone clever once wrote that "It is not possible to both understand and appreciate the Intel CPU.", so assembler is right out.

Comment: I upvoted the post from @ojosilva, because it's all true, and my comments may not have reflected that.  It added value.